# How to use find to find a file in specified subdirectory

Tags: find

I have multiple sites that user my own template, now I have updated my template and I want to update the template using find.

if I do

```
find . -name template.css -print -exec cp NEW_FILE {} \;
```

Then all other template.css wil overwritten to.

I only want template.css to be overwritten if they are in the directory mytemplate/css.

Any one an idea?

Example:

```
/site1/templates/mytemplate/css/template.css*
/site1/templates/othertemplate/css/template.css
/site1/templates/other2template/css/template.css
/site2/templates/mytemplate/css/template.css*
/site2/templates/othertemplate/css/template.css
/site2/templates/other2template/css/template.css
/site3/templates/mytemplate/css/template.css*
/site3/templates/othertemplate/css/template.css
/site3/templates/other2template/css/template.css
```

The files with an * should only be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-wholename` flag and proper regular expression. This should work for your example:

```
find . -wholename "*/mytemplate/css/template.css" -print -exec cp NEW_FILE {} \;
```

Comment: And we have the "-iwholename" to do a case insensitive search.